# Making text vertically centered in a button

Tags: android

I have buttons in `RelativeLayout`. **Height and width** are not `wrap_content`. I noticed that the text in `Button` is not vertically centered. How can I fix this problem in my code?

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="&lt;"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousDay"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextShowDate"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to set padding

```
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. My actual problem was padding.

Comment: textSize should not be in dp change it to sp